# Why CRON_TZ setting not work at /etc/crontab?

Tags: bash, shell, cron, timezone

Set `CRON_TZ` in the `/etc/crontab`

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
CRON_TZ=Asia/Tokyo

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

Created a cron job under one user as

```
crontab -e
0 1 * * * echo 'task' > /tmp/task
```

It didn't run at 1 o'clock in Tokyo. But before 9 hours. It's UTC. Why `/etc/crontab` not work globally?

Comment: Based on what I've found while googling, it varies wildly by distro and version, but you probably either need to set an additional `TZ` variable or update the timezone in `/etc/localtime`.

Comment: @SomethingDark `/etc/localtime` is a binary file. I can add `TZ` to `/etc/crontab`.